# need help filling the array in java

Tags: java

i need to fill the array with * and space, this is what i have so far

```
/*
 *   sets this.phrase array to the passed input
 *   creates this.maskedPhrase array and
 *   fills this.maskedPhrase with * or space characters
 */

public void setGame(char... input)
{

    this.phrase = input;
    this.maskedPhrase = new char[input.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < this.maskedPhrase.length; i++){
        this.maskedPhrase[i] = input[i];
    }            
    System.out.println("IMPLEMENT setGame method");

}
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example, so we can execute it.

Comment: just change `this.maskedPhrase[i] = input[i];` to `this.maskedPhrase[i] = '*';`

Answer (score 1):

I believe, based on context, you were supposed to fill `maskedPhrase` with `'*'` or `' '` (**not** *copy* `input` to `maskedPhrase`). Like,

```
public void setGame(char... input) {
    this.phrase = input;
    this.maskedPhrase = new char[input.length];
    Arrays.fill(this.maskedPhrase, '*');
}
```